# How do you pass encoded parameters in Rails via a redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, redirect, url-routing

This may be a fairly simple question, but my goal here is to redirect to another part of my application and pass parameters confidently.

Right now, I want to pass the :mobile and :content parameters from "/xxx" to "/yyy".

Parameters come in clean and fine into "/xxx", but I am currently passing them like so:

```
  redirect_to "/yyy?mobile=#{params[:mobile]}&content=#{params[:content]}"
```

Despite this working, this seems to have an encoding issue. Spaces come up as "%20" and not "+" for one as well as it seeming generally dirty.

Comment: why didn't you use route helpers? i think creating such routes is bad practice in rails..

Comment: yea, sadly this was a rubber-band fix. do you have any resources for route helpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [url_encode](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/erb/1.8.7/ERB/Util%3aurl_encode) method, example :

```
redirect_to url_encode("/yyy?mobile=#{params[:mobile]}&content=#{params[:content]}")
```

Or simply use redirect_to with parameters :

```
redirect_to :action => 'toto', :param_1 => 'titi', :param_2 => 'tata'
```

Answer (score 0):

As i've said in comment creating such routes is bad practice in rails.

So you should set route in routes.rb and then use route like:

```
redirect_to yyy_path(:mobile => params[:mobile], :content => params[:content])
```

for more information follow http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html